# How to automatically render an htmlpage using urllib form currently working page in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

Basically I am  trying to automatically render an html page using `urllib` from currently working page. It has to happen when another function runs, which also renders a page.

- On one side lets consider **first.html** page where 
  `"form action='myweb/google'"` - on submit i have to go to google
- At the same time in **second.html** page i have to automatically render to google itself when i submit the button in first.html

Comment: I think it's unclear, Any examples?

Comment: Your intent is vague to me, perhaps you want a regular view which returns `render` of one template on `GET` and of another template on `POST`.